# Why don't I get a notification when InkFilePicker downloads a file from a Box account?

Tags: box-api, filepicker.io

I have a Box application that has Even Notifications enabled for all events. I tested it with multiple accounts and triggering different events; it works fine. I use InkFilePicker to choose a file from Box. Following the InkFilePicker link also works fine.

The way this works (as I understand), InkFilePicker downloads a copy of the file from Box to S3 and gives me a URL that points to the copy. Then how come I don't get notified of the download?

**What I'm trying to do is**

- Let a user choose a Box file.
- Get this file's id to process its Event Notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked them and this was their response:

> We don't download a file from your box. The file is uploaded from your
>   box account when you select a file and hit upload. As a developer you
>   can see these files in your admin account.